# Alfresco: ScriptTaskListener javascript code not executed

Tags: jakarta-ee, alfresco

I'm building a custom workflow in alfresco, I'm setting the value of two execution variables as follows

```
<startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start" activiti:formKey="swwf:AssignmentTask">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:executionListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[logger.log("Log Start");
                        execution.setVariable('translator', task.getVariable(swwf_translator));
                        execution.setVariable('reviewer', task.getVariable(swwf_reviewer));]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:executionListener>
      </extensionElements>
</startEvent>
```

The type in workflow model corresponding to the start task is

```
        <type name="swwf:AssignmentTask" >
            <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
             <associations>
                <association name="swwf:translator">
                    <title>Translator</title>
                    <source>
                        <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                        <many>false</many>
                    </source>
                    <target>
                        <class>cm:person</class>
                        <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                        <many>false</many>
                    </target>
                </association>
                <association name="swwf:reviewer">
                    <title>Reviewer</title>
                    <source>
                        <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                        <many>false</many>
                    </source>
                    <target>
                        <class>cm:person</class>
                        <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                        <many>false</many>
                    </target>
                </association>
          </associations>
        </type>
```

Comment: Why are you so sure that the code is not executed ? If it is because you do not see the log message, it is also possible that you need to increase the log level. By default these messages are not printed.

Comment: I've already setup the log4j.properties to increase the log level to debug,

Comment: @Basil what log level are you talking about ? root logger ? javascript logger ? how did you set up your log4j ?

Answer (score 0):

How sure are about that javascript not being executed ?

If you do not have the appropriate log level setup in your `project-name-repo/src/main/amp/config/alfresco/module/project-name-repo`like this: `log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptLogger=DEBUG` then you probably won't get any output in your log !

If you got confused and couldn't verify if your *log4j.properties* is being loaded correctly, try `logger.error("message");` to be sure if the js snippet is being executed correctly !

> Logging info/debug messages as errors is highly unrecommended, in fact it goes against coding standards, so be sure to revert back to `logger.log()` once you verify the log message in your console.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain there is an issue in the way you setup the listener.

```
activiti:executionListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
```

You are calling an executionListener, but assigning it a task listener class. Additionally, "complete" is a task listener event, not an execution event. If you want this to fire when you submit the start form, you need to change the event to "start". Instead, that should be like this:

```
activiti:executionListener event="start" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.listener.ScriptExecutionListener">
```

Also, there are issues with the script being run. I just had essentially the same thing [in this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017229/activiti-workflow-setting-value-of-an-aspect-from-starttask)

1. `task.getVariable(swwf_translator)` when you are referring to a property itself and not the contents of it (like you are here) you need to surround the property in quotes. Otherwise, task will try to fetch a variable and it will interpret the value of swwf_translator as a string referring to a different variable. Like this: `task.getVariable("swwf_translator")`
2. You can't actually refer to "task" in the start event. This is because start events are essentially before the process begins, and not a task at all. So trying to grab the values from it this way won't work. (This is what my SO question was about. Check out responses there.)
3. If you are trying to pass these values around the process, you probably want to use aspects instead. If you make an aspect with these fields, set it as a mandatory aspect for the start task, and reference those fields (make sure you don't refer to the aspect itself like I did by mistake) then the information you put in at the start form will be automatically put into the execution level. In fact, you should also be able to pull it down for other forms just by having them also use the given aspect and not have to script the task.setVariableLocal(xxx, execution.getVariable(xxx)) stuff.
4. I think the way you are trying to set the execution value shouldn't work in general (ignoring above reasons). `execution.setVariable('translator', task.getVariable(swwf_translator));` Instead of 'translator', you should use the full id 'swwf_translator' like you did with the task part.