# Activiti workflow: setting value of an aspect from StartTask

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I need to set a value from a text field on my start form and then pull this information on several other tasks. To do this, I'm using an aspect and trying to send the data up to the execution variable, and then pull it down.

The problem is that I cannot send the value from the start form to the execution variable. As it is now, Share will just say that the workflow cannot be started.

I am using Alfresco 4.2.f Community edition.

The start event is defined in the BPMN as follows:

```
<startEvent id="start" name="Start Delivery Ticket Workflow" activiti:initiator="initiatorUserName" activiti:formKey="deliveryTicketWorkflow:start">
  <documentation>Project Manager initiates workflow. A customer purchase order is provided, along with the specific line items for the delivery ticket.</documentation>
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:executionListener class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.listener.ExecutionListener" event="start">
      <activiti:field name="script">
        <activiti:string><![CDATA[  
             execution.setVariable('deliveryTicketWorkflow_requestdetailstext', task.getVariable('deliveryTicketWorkflow_requestdetailstext'));;
         ]]></activiti:string>
      </activiti:field>
    </activiti:executionListener>
  </extensionElements> 
</startEvent>
```

The relevant parts of my model are:

```
<type name="deliveryTicketWorkflow:start">
  <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
  <properties />
  <associations />
  <overrides />
  <mandatory-aspects>
    <aspect>deliveryTicketWorkflow:requestdetails</aspect>
  </mandatory-aspects>
</type>
[...]
 <aspect name="deliveryTicketWorkflow:requestdetails">
  <properties>
    <property name="deliveryTicketWorkflow:requestdetailstext">
      <title>Specific Details</title>
      <type>d:text</type>
      <mandatory>true</mandatory>
      <multiple>false</multiple>
    </property>
  </properties>
</aspect>
```

In the config:

```
<config condition="deliveryTicketWorkflow:start" evaluator="task-type">
    <forms>
        <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="packageItems"/>
                <show id="deliveryTicketWorkflow:requestdetailstext"/>
                <show id="transitions"/>
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <set appearance="title" label-id="Prepare Delivery Ticket" id="info"/>
                <field set="info" id="packageItems"/>
                <field set="info" label-id="Request Details" id="deliveryTicketWorkflow:requestdetailstext">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl"/>
                </field>
                <set id="response"/>
                <field set="response" id="transitions"/>
            </appearance>
        </form>
    </forms>
</config>
[...]
<config condition="activiti$deliveryTicketWorkflow" evaluator="string-compare">
    <forms>
        <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="bpm:workflowPriority"/>
                <show id="packageItems"/>
                <show id="deliveryTicketWorkflow:requestdetails"/>
                <show id="transitions"/>
                <show id="deliveryTicketWorkflow:approveRejectOutcome"/>
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <set appearance="title" label-id="Request Delivery Ticket" id="info"/>
                <field set="info" label-id="workflow.field.priority" id="bpm:workflowPriority">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/priority.ftl"/>
                </field>
                <field set="info" id="packageItems"/>
                <field set="info" label-id="Request Details" id="deliveryTicketWorkflow:requestdetails">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl"/>
                </field>
                <set id="response"/>
                <field set="response" id="approveRejectOutcome">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/activiti-transitions.ftl"/>
                </field>
                <field set="response" id="transitions"/>
            </appearance>
        </form>
    </forms>
</config>
```

I have seen at least one question here that was similar, but the answers were stating to use task listeners for the start form. I'm not sure at all how that is intended to function, because it seems like a start task isn't a "true" task and can only use ExecutionListeners. The difference should be small, but it seems that any reference to "task" in the start task will either cause a failure or just have no affect at all. Becasue I can't use task.getVariableLocal() to get the value, I don't see what to give to execution.setVariable() as the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, all values of aspects and properties in a start task are automatically copied to the executionContext and are already available for future tasks.

Try removing the executionlistener in your BPMN, you shouldnt need that. Then try making a starttasklistener on your subsequent task that copyies the value from your execeutioncontext into this task. It should work fine.

Getting the var back from your executioncontext in your subsequent task should work like this:

```
<activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener"> 
   <activiti:field name="language" stringValue="groovy" /
   <activiti:field name="script"> 
   <activiti:string><![CDATA[
   System.out.println(execution.getVariable("deliveryTicketWorkflow_requestdetailstext"));        
   if (execution.getVariable("deliveryTicketWorkflow_requestdetailstext") != null){
     task.setVariableLocal('deliveryTicketWorkflow_requestdetailstext', execution.getVariable("deliveryTicketWorkflow_requestdetailstext"));
    }]]>
   </activiti:string>
</activiti:field>
</activiti:taskListener>
```

Comment: Like this in the task that needs to read it? Because that's not working for me.

`<activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[
                if (typeof deliveryTicketWorkflow_requestdetailstext != 'undefined'){ 
                        task.setVariableLocal('deliveryTicketWorkflow_requestdetailstext', deliveryTicketWorkflow_requestdetailstext);
                };]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>`

Comment: To clarify: The task runs fine when I remove the execution listener and have the above task listener in the next task, but the message still doesn't move from the starting form to the 2nd form

Comment: You should get the value out of your execution context object (execution.getVariable("deliveryTicketWorkflow_requestdetailstext")). I ve updated my answer

Comment: This makes perfect sense, and I changed that task's script to exactly that (start event is empty, no listeners there at all anymore) and it is still not moving data.

fwiw: all other tasks are moving data just fine. It's just the text coming from start that I can't get.

Comment: weird... try logging the value (as shown in updated answer) to see if the value is in the execution object. If so, the error may be in the form/content model definition.

Comment: I put one logger in an unrelated executionListener for the start event, and one in the normal taskListener for the create event on the first task to read the value. For both of them, the value returned was null.

Comment: I am a complete and total idiot. I've been staring at this thing for days and not realizing that I had referred to the aspect name on the form and not the actual property I wanted. Once I fixed that, everything you said did exactly what you said it should do.

Comment: It s OK, I missed that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but in your share form, your custom field is using the info control:

I believe you need there to be a regular field there, the info field is to display text, AFAIK, it doesn't include an input field and won't send anything to the workflow start.

Comment: Your suggestion is true, the info formcontrol does not support data modification, and does not submit any data (not even a default data or a pre-entered value) and since the model for the start task has `deliveryTicketWorkflow:requestdetails` as a mandatory aspect which has `deliveryTicketWorkflow:requestdetailstext` as a mandatory property causing the workflow to fail to start because it is missing some mandatory data. This, however, does not help the OP pass some data from start task to some other task later ...

Comment: @MichaelKay: can you start the process (even though you are not able to retrieve the value from your start event later on some other task) ?

Comment: I can not currently start the process. I see nothing in alfresco.log, alfrescotomcat-stderr.log, or alfrescotomcat-stdout.log detailing why it fails.

Comment: It seems that the start form is actually pulling from activiti$deliveryTicketWorkflow instead of deliveryTicketWorkflow:start, despite deliveryTicketWorkflow:start being the form key. I have updated the posted config to include that.